# cudaMemcpy not actually copying anything

Tags: c, cuda

I'm trying to copy an array of unsigned ints (in `msgs`) onto the GPU to work on them, but the following code isn't copying anything. I threw in some cuda error checking code around the `cudaMemcpy` call, and I'm getting the following: `invalid argument`.

```
...
unsigned int *device_msgs;
size_t size_msgs = (size_t)(16*num_msgs);
cudaMalloc((void **) &device_msgs, size_msgs);

cudaMemcpy(device_msgs, msgs,
                   sizeof(unsigned int)*16*num_msgs,
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
...
```

I wrapped the `cudaMalloc` in the same error checking code, nothing seemingly wrong there. The actual kernel call results in the same `invalid argument` cuda error, but that might have to do with the `memCpys`, since I'm passing in the device pointers. Anyone know what's going on here?

EDIT: To be clear, `msgs` is properly malloc'd beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to allocate 16*num_msgs bytes for the device_msgs and then try to copy in much more than that due to the sizeof(unsigned int) multiplier.  Try changing it to:

```
unsigned int *device_msgs;
size_t size_msgs = sizeof(unsigned int)*16*num_msgs;
cudaMalloc((void **) &device_msgs, size_msgs);

cudaMemcpy(device_msgs, msgs, size_msgs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Comment: check `msgs` also... if OP misunderstood how to specify the size for `device_msgs`, may have also done the same problem with `msgs`.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem, thanks a bunch. I definitely malloc'd the right size, I triple checked that earlier, but thanks for the suggestion.